À + infinitive at start of sentence
Please consider this sentence:

À supposer que cet agent, au coin du boulevard, l’arrête

I think I know what it means but I can’t find any references to the grammar.
In what circumstances should one begin a sentence with à + an infinitive?
Could the infinitive be used without the à and, if so, how would then affect the meaning?
Any online references would be appreciated. (I have Grevisse but with my limited command of French could find nothing there.)

You cannot remove the initial À: this would turn the infinitive clause into the subject of the main clause, when it is in fact a relative clause. It would be easier to explain if your example extended to the end of the main clause.

À vaincre sans péril, on triomphe sans gloire.

A truncated sentence such as in the OP is difficult to analyze. Instead, consider this example:

À supposer que cet agent l'arrête, nous n'avons rien pour l'incriminer.

The infinitive clause À supposer is a relative clause, with the secondary relative que cet agent l'arrête its direct object. Its function is adverbial or circumstantial in the main clause: it is grammatically equivalent to En supposant (que cet agent l'arrête).
The infinitive clause has to be introduced with a preposition, such as À: else, it could only parse as the subject of the main clause, making the whole sentence ungrammatical.
A grammatical counter-example would be:

Supposer que cet agent l'arrête serait espérer de celui-ci  trop d'intuition.

As the subject of serait, the infinitive clause is not introduced by a preposition. Neither is the attribute espérer, mark.
